# Parent-Child Mode cannot be searched by parent column

Tags: vespa

I follow this article
https://blog.vespa.ai/parent-child-in-vespa/

this is OK

```
vespa query -v 'yql=select * from ad where ad_campaign_budget < 500'
```

but this cannot find any result

```
vespa query -v 'yql=select * from ad where ad_campaign_budget < 500 and ad_campaign_company_name contains "ACME"'
```

i found that even if i want to search the simple advertiser like this will return no result

```
vespa query -v 'yql=select * from advertiser where company_name contains "ACME"'
```

i think maybe in advertiser.sd, field "company_name" didn't declair to indexing: index
but when i add index and deploy, it shows me that index in global not support, like this

```
For schema 'campaign', import field 'campaign_company_name':
Field 'company_name' via reference field 'advertiser_ref':
Is an index field. Not supported
```

how can i let company_name filed be indexed and be searched ?

Answer (score 3):

That query example in this blog post is unfortunately wrong and will cause 0 results. Fields that are imported into child document types need to be defined with `indexing: attribute`. And `attribute` fields do not support `match:text` where the document text is tokenized, stemmed, and normalized and where "ACME" would match. See [match](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/schema-reference.html#match). [This guide](https://docs.vespa.ai/en/performance/practical-search-performance-guide.html#searching-attribute-fields) also describes the difference in matching with regards to `index` versus `attribute`.

Comment: Also, the blog post was rather badly formatted, thanks for bringing it to our attention. We will update it.

Comment: But I need "company_name" to be tokenized, through my Tokenizer logic to split word into each tokens to be searched, how can I do ?

another question is, in this case, is any example to search on company_name field and get result ?

Comment: You can search for company_name contains "ACME Inc. cats and rocket equipment", you can also use prefix, or even also regular expressions using matches instead of contains. You can do custom tokenization and store tokens in an array<string> attribute.

Comment: custom tokenization and store tokens in an array<string> attribute, but this array<string> can be imported by child ?

Comment: do you mean that i need to write another duplicate code like my tokenize code, to process company_name to tokenize and store it to array<sting>, and then import this array<string> in my child sd file ?

Comment: You can import array fields and yes, since attribute match modes does not support text mode with tokenization and stemming.

Comment: I fixed the formatting in https://blog.vespa.ai/parent-child-in-vespa/ , it is readable now